# Can I reprogram my SPI flash wirelessly?

Tags: spi, programming, flash, wireless-charging

I am working on an application which stores specific model information in the SPI flash. The hardware is the same between the five different types of units. They are typically programmed with model information at end of line test in a fixture.

I'm sure there is a technology which exists that would allow me to reprogram model information in the unit once it is all boxed up and palatalized.

What is this technology called and are there any good resources for getting started in it?

Comment: I'd call it "Write that Feature into your Firmware".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There certainly is a technology that allows an EEPROM to be reprogrammed wirelessly. The parts go by different names, such as Dual Interface EEPROM, or RFID Memory, or NFC Memory.  A key facet of this technology is that it doesn't require the EEPROM to be powered; it is powered by the NFC or RFID field. ST make these parts, and I think NXP do too. Have a look at [NFC / RFID Memories and Transceivers](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/mmc/FM76/CL1766?sc=dualeeprom) from ST.

I am not sure what range you can get with these parts, I imagine that you can program the EEPROM when the product has been boxed, but I'm not sure you will be able to do it once palatalized.

Comment: The link at the ST website you posted has great information to get me started.